# cfhttp : the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, security, ssl, coldfusion

I am making a cfhttp call from my main server to reporting server. And it was working fine until few days ago.

But suddenly it has started giving errors when I am trying to make http call through cfhttp.
Following is the error dump :

```
Charset     [empty string]
ErrorDetail     I/O Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Filecontent     Connection Failure
Header  [empty string]
Mimetype    Unable to determine MIME type of file.
Responseheader  
struct [empty]
Statuscode  Connection Failure. Status code unavailable.
Text    YES
```

Because this error has start coming all of sudden.I suspect is it because of automatic java update.

I had seen some links related truststore key missing , but nothing was related to coldfusion.

Anyone having idea regarding this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading java to latest version i.e. "jre1.8.0_60" on both the servers resolved my problem.

Comment: Updating your answer with the relevant version information (CF, old/new java versions) might help the next guy.